# R - how to set a specific number of PCA components to train a prediction model

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data

Using train() and preProcess() I want to build a predictive model using PCA with the first 7 principal components as my predictors.

The below works but I'm not able to specify the number of PCs:

```
predModel2 <- train(diagnosis~., data=training2, method = "glm", preProcess = "pca")
```

I've tried this to specify the number of PCs but I don't know how to incorporate it into train():

```
training_pre<-preProcess(training[,ILcols],method = c("center", "scale", "pca"),pcaComp= 7)
```

I've tried using:

```
predModel2 <- train(diagnosis~., data=training2, method = "glm", preProcess = "pca", pcaComp=7)
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
```

UPDATE:
It seems I get around this by using predict() first:

```
training2_pca<-predict(training_pre,training2_pca)
train(diagnosis~., data=training2_pca, method = "glm")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All preprocessing should be done within the training folds or, in this case, resamples. That prevents 'data leaks', so the first of the above approaches should be preferred, see e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/pca-and-k-fold-cross-validation-in-caret).

The `pcaComp` argument goes into `trainControl()`. Using the iris data, KNN and the first two principal components as an example:

```
predModel2 <- train(Species~., data=iris, method = "knn", preProcess = "pca",
                    trControl = trainControl(preProcOptions = list(pcaComp = 2)))
```